# How to implemenet REST API for developed Spring java project

Tags: java, spring, rest

How to implement REST API for already developed Spring java Project (it has service and DAO layer alone no controller)

I asked this in general how should implement REST API in spring java project.

I have developed Spring + hibernate project i want to implement REST API on that how can we do that can anyone explain me with an example that should call Service Layer -> DAO Layer to persist or retrieve from DB.

Comment: a) what have you tried? b) what is your code? c) what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking a spring-styled framework to export your DB service as a RESTful web service, the [spring data rest project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) may helps you.